# assert List<Map> contains String

Tags: list, dictionary, groovy, contains, assert

I am trying to make an assertion the only issue is the order could be random so I can't do a normal compare so I need to use something along the lines of `.contains` the only problem it the below does not work.

```
List<Map> aliasQueryResults
Map<String, String> newTokenValuesMap
assert aliasQueryResults.contains(newTokenValuesMap.get("{BASEALIAS}"))
```

`newTokenValuesMap.get("{BASEALIAS}")` is fine it returns the string so it's not the issue of this attempt.

Comment: Could you please provide any running example that shows the problem?

Comment: You are trying to see if a List of Maps contains a String... it wont.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the List is really a `List<Map<String, String>>`, and what you want is to see if a value is represented in any of the values from any of the maps in the list, then you can pull out the values from the maps:

```
aliasQueryResults*.values().flatten().contains(newTokenValuesMap.get("{BASEALIAS}"))
```

example:

```
groovy:000> mylist = []
===> []
groovy:000> mylist << [a:'asdf', b:'zxcv', c:'qwer']
===> [[a:asdf, b:zxcv, c:qwer]]
groovy:000> mylist << [d:'xcvb',e:'wert', f:'sdfg']
===> [[a:asdf, b:zxcv, c:qwer], [d:xcvb, e:wert, f:sdfg]]
groovy:000> mylist*.values()
===> [[asdf, zxcv, qwer], [xcvb, wert, sdfg]]
groovy:000> mylist*.values().flatten()
===> [asdf, zxcv, qwer, xcvb, wert, sdfg]
groovy:000> mylist*.values().flatten().contains('asdf')
===> true
```